# UnsupportedOperationException Error while opening camera android

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-bitmap

I am doing an Android application which need to open camera and display picture on screen and take that picture absolute path.

But I always get `"UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown URI: content://media/external/images/media"` error when I click on camera.

**My code:**

```
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "ircms");
        imgUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values); // Here getting error
        Intent intentPicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imgUri);
        startActivityForResult(intentPicture, 1);
```

**onActivityResult:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            try {
                String photoPath = getRealPathFromURI(this, imgUri);
                o2.inSampleSize = 8;
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, o2);
                }
       }
}
```

Please Help...

Comment: Do you made changes in "Manifest FIle" to support "media","External storage"???

Comment: Yes I have added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: is it happening on emulator or real device?

Comment: Real device. It is working on lenovo Tab but to working on Zolo Android mobile.

Comment: see my answer !!!! may you forget to give camera permission

Comment: give a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity/5991757#5991757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

What Do you Need
In Manafiest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In your activity

```
private static final int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 1;

private void takePhoto(){
  final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(this)) ); 
  startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
}

private File getTempFile(Context context){
  //it will return /sdcard/image.tmp
  final File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getPackageName() );
  if(!path.exists()){
    path.mkdir();
  }
  return new File(path, "image.tmp");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    switch(requestCode){
      case TAKE_PHOTO_CODE:
        final File file = getTempFile(this);
        try {
          Bitmap captureBmp = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file) );
          // do whatever you want with the bitmap (Resize, Rename, Add To Gallery, etc)
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying your answer but it is asking me to create Media.getBitmap(); function.

Comment: you have to import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media

Comment: see doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Media.html

Comment: no you dont need! just import android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media

Comment: if you are usng eclipse than just press ctrl+shift+O

Comment: Tried, but not getting imported.:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44492/discussion-between-user2085965-and-hardik)

Comment: Your post and you helped me a lot. Thank you so much.:)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get file path of the image in onActivityResult

```
Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else { 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
        return cursor.getString(idx); 
    }
}
```